# uln2803apg toshiba shows noise

Tags: arduino, transistors

I'm using an arduino to send a 5v signal to other devices. I'm using the uln2803apg
to drive a 5v 3ampere signal.

The problem, when i look at this output signal i'm seeing a lot of noise, which is not visible on the pin controlling the uln2803apg.

[image]

Within the peaks you notice the noise,

[image]

I'm clearly not an experienced electrical engineer, however any ideas or comments
would be greatly appreciated.

Regards Auke

Comment: The Absolute Maximum output current of the ULN2803 is 500 mA per channel.  It cannot handle 3 Amps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ULN2803 is an inverting open collector driver and the noise you are seeing is likely due to high frequency pick-up when the device is open circuiting between pulses. Try lowering (or connecting) a pull-up load to your local Vcc and see how the noise reduces in amplitude.

Here's what a single channel looks like: -

[image]

If you need to drive a digital signal from one PCB to another there are push-pull drivers that might be better suited.

Comment: Hi Andy, sorry for the late reply. Suddenly got shifted to a different project. Got it working with your schematic! Thanx

Comment: @user1875444 please feel free to formally accept the answer and / or upvote! Pleased to hear this.